# Integrating shopify database in React native

Tags: react-native, e-commerce, shopify

I need a solution to connect shopify database to my mobile application database as i am developing Mobile app in React Native.
Ecommerce Website built on shopify and need to connect it to mobile App database.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Shopify API](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/getting-started) for that.

Comment: @VivekSehgal please accept the answer if it helped you out